# Shall the requestAnimationFrame calls always be throttled down to 60 FPS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

`requestAnimationFrame` is called whenever the screen is ready for a repaint.
On modern screens the refresh rate may be a lot higher then 60 frames per second. If there is a lot of stuff going on inside those calls - it may impact the overall performance of the application.

So my question is: shall the `requestAnimationFrame` always be throttled down to 60FPS? Can human eye actually tell the difference between for example a 16ms and an 8ms repaint delay?

[UPDATE]
I ended up throttling it down to 60FPS for higher performance on screens with high refresh rate.
And would suggest this approach to everyone who has a lot of stuff goin on inside the rAF calls.
You should do your own testing of course though.

Comment: Well, if there is lots of stuff going on inside those callbacks, then the next animation frame will necessarily be delayed. "animation frame" is not tied to the screen refresh rate!

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Do you have any reference by any chance?

Comment: No, and in fact I might have been incorrect (see the quote from klyd's answer). The browser is smart and tries to synchronize framerate (js animation frame callback + reflow + redraw) with the screen refreshes for a smooth experience. However, it will automatically throttle it when there is (too) much js work per frame, the battery is running low, the tab is not shown etc.

Comment: Just to avoid misleading comment to slip through : there's no such thing as automatic throttle. And no such thing as framerate synchronization. that's sad, but there's no magic here.

Comment: If the JavaScript code in the callback specified to `requestAnimationFrame()` runs longer than a single frame, then, yes, you will force a frame skip which is itself automatic throttling. You should only put things in `requestAnimationFrame()` if they are things which cause a user-visible change (such as calculating positions). Wanting to skip frames to “increase performance” will result in less fluidity in your animations and a perception of lower performance/jagginess on your page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) it will not necessarily always be 60 FPS.

Relevant quote:

> This will request that your animation function be called before the browser performs the next repaint. The number of callbacks is usually 60 times per second, but will ***generally match the display refresh rate in most web browsers as per W3C recommendation***. The callback rate may be reduced to a lower rate when running in background tabs.

As for can the human eye distinguish 60 vs 120 FPS, well, that's an open, and opinionated question. Some claim to see it, other's claim its impossible. Allowing the end user to choose is (or simply using their hardware to its fullest) probably best.

As [markE's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120838/shall-the-requestanimationframe-calls-always-be-throttled-down-to-60-fps/26121067#comment40948739_26121067) pointed out. The [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame#Parameters) callback receives a [`DOMHighResTimeStamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp) which is a high precision timer accurate to the "[thousandth of a millisecond.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp)" By using this time-stamp, and calculating the delta between frames, you can tune your refresh rate to whatever desired value.

**References:**

- [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame)
- [W3C Timing control for script-based animations](http://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/#Window-interface-extensions)
- [DOMHighResTimeStamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp)

***Note:*** please remember to leave a comment addressing any downvotes, otherwise they are not useful feedback.

Comment: I think the end user might not always be aware of the implications of executing JS so many times a second, I am mostly worried because JS is single-threaded and if `rAF` gets too 'laggy' - it will affect the whole application performance, not just the redraw loop. But I guess I'll need to come up with some tests and see for myself.

Comment: Absolutely. You also don't necessarily want to use '`rAF`' for timing events. Instead for precision timing could use [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now). Using that you can clamp your redraws to every ***n*** milliseconds of your choice.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. Just a note...browsers now send in a timestamp parameter into RAF.  This means you can calculate the elapsed time since the RAF loop was last executed. This lets you throttle RAF to your desired interval ;-)

Comment: @markE Thanks for the timestamp parameter tip! Very useful when trying to optimize everything as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that people having 120hz or higher frame rate displays are aware that it requires more resources to generate twice as much frames.

That and/or they have more powerful computers than most users. I personally have a very powerful PC but two 60hz displays and the only guy I know that has a display with a higher framerate than 60hz is a pro gamer so obviously he has no performance issue when browsing the web.

Also, people using very high framerate displays are getting used to that level of fluidity and they might notice the difference (event if I doubt it).

My two cents are : respect their preference of having an overkill display. It's what they want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think there is a difference between simply redrawing the screen and redrawing the screen + calling a JS function. Also a high refresh rate does not necessarily mean good hardware, for example - all the displays where I work are 144Hz, but some of the machines a 7-8 years old.

Answer (score -4):

By default, i think it is good to limit the framerate to 60Hz, since :

• High framerate means more heat, so the (cpu) fan noise will be annoying.
• For most game nobody will notice.
• it's easy to do.
• For those with ecological concerns, high fps uses more power (==> more CO2).

About the visual interest of 120 Hz :
For 2D games where only a tiny amount of the screen is actually changed between each frame it's of little to no interest.
For 3D games, especially those targeting to be realistic, using 120Hz allows to get a more 'cinema'-like experience.
Why ?
==> Most 3D renderers only render a scene at a *point* in time, so what you see is a succession of 'perfect' still images.
On the other hand, a real camera will -like the human eye- be kept open for a few milliseconds, thus the moves happening during this time will leave a trail on the image, providing a more true to life experience.

The 60Hz boundary is only enough to fool the eye about the motion, so what the 120Hz+ screen brings is that the screen is so fast eye remanence cannot follow and you have again that camera/eye trail effect.

The code looks like :

```
var minFrame = 13;
var maxFrame = 19;
var typicalFrame = 16;

var gameTime = 0;

var lastDrawTime = -1;

animate(drawTime) {
   requestAnimationFrame(animate);
   var dt = drawTime - lastDrawTime;
   lastDrawTime = drawTime ;
   if (dt<minFrame) return;
   if (dt>maxFrame) dt=typicalFrame; // in case of a tab-out
   gameTime+=dt;
   // ...
}

function lauchAnimation() {
    requestAnimationFrame ( function(t) { lastDrawTime = t;
                                          requestAnimationFrame(animate);  } );        
}
```

Rq1 : When you limit the fps, you must take care of the fact that the frame rate is *not* stable at all in a Browser.
So even with an application doing nothing, on a 60Hz screen, has frame duration that can go from 14ms to 19ms. (!!!!) So you must take some margin when capping the frame rate to some value.

Rq2 : In the example above 'typicalFrame' is to be replaced by the native screen frame rate (that you have to compute by yourself).

Comment: No reason to do this manually. If the browser (who is authoritative!) thinks it needs to save energy or let the CPU cool down, it will automatically throttle the frame rate.

Comment: Really? I did understand http://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/: "*Using this API should result in more appropriate utilization of the CPU by the browser.*" like that.

Comment: Yes, rAF is more 'appropriate' since you draw in sync with the display. With a setInterval you might both draw for nothing or miss a frame. But just have a try on a 120Hz+ display, you'll see that fan goes crazy even if the computer is mobile and battery is low. In fact it's the fan noise/battery life of my own(120Hz) computer that made me aware of that issue, i wouldn't have guess that was such a resource strain before seing it.